# Thermal voltage of Ge diode

Tags: voltage, diodes, thermal

What is the thermal voltage of a Ge diode?I know for a silicon diode is about 26mV at room temperature.

I have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4TNm1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and a set of equation where X = Current through the diodes , Y = Voltage drop of Si diode and Z = Voltage drop of Ge diode:

x = (3-y-z)/1000

x = (10^-12)*(e^(y/0.026)-1)

x = (10^-9)*(e^(z/Vt(Ge))-1)

and I need it (at room temperature) so help really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thermal voltage does not depend on the semiconductor material; it's simply

$$V_T = \frac{kT}{q},$$

where \$k\$ is the Boltzmann constant, \$k = 1.380649 × 10^{-23}\ \mathrm{J}·\mathrm{K}^{-1},\ T\$ is the temperature, and \$q\$ is the electron charge, \$q=1.602176634 × 10^{-19}\ \mathrm{C}.\$

At 25 °C, this works out to approximately 26 mV, and does not depend on material.